# alternative to LocalTime checking if time is in range between two times

Tags: java, android

I have a code that supports only API Level >= 26 in android:

```
public static String in = "7:00:00";
public static String in_until = "11:50:00";
public static String breakout_out = "11:51:00";
public static String breakout_out_until = "12:50:00";
public static String breakout_in = "12:51:00";
public static String breakout_in_until = "13:10:00";
public static String out = "16:50";

public static String getCurrentTimeLogType() {
    // LocalTime target = LocalTime.parse( DataHandler.timestamp().split(" ")[1] ) ;
    LocalTime target = LocalTime.parse("7:30:00") ;
    if (target.isBefore(in) || (target.isAfter(in) && target.isBefore(in_until)))
        return "TIME-IN";
    else if (target.isAfter(breakout_out) && target.isBefore(breakout_out_until))
        return "BREAK-OUT";
    else if (target.isAfter(breakout_in) && target.isBefore(breakout_in_until))
        return "BREAK IN";
    else  if (target.isAfter(out))
        return "TIME-OUT";

    return "UNKNOWN!";
}
```

I want to return if the specified time in the variables is within the current time to return what type of timestamp to add to database.

For example if today is 12:05 PM:

```
if (12:05 >= breakout_out && 12:05 <= breakout_out_until)
    return "BREAK-OUT"
```

I want to achieve something like this. How can I achieve a code like this without using the unsupported LocalTime module?

Comment: You could consider using the backport: https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/ and https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like below. Not tested though.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date breakout_out = sdf.parse("11:51:00");
Date breakout_out_until = sdf.parse("13:10:00");
Date current_time = sdf.parse("12.05.00");

if(current_time.before(breakout_out_until) && current_time.after(breakout_out)) {
    return "BREAK-OUT"
}
```